# error when accessing OData with a number as a filter

Tags: odata, hana, sapui5

I am trying to access an OData source provider, specifically an analytic view exposed by SAP HANA via Odata service. I'am applying a filter containing a number on odata but I am getting an error saying that using the number is not supported because of

```
  "Operator 'eq' incompatible with operand types 'Edm.Decimal' and 'Edm.String'
```

this is how I am accessing the resource:

```
 analyticView.xsodata/analyticView?$select=AMOUNT_SOLD,FAMILY_NAME&$filter=SALE_PRICE%20eq%20'323.7'&$format=json
```

I also tried to remove the quotes from the number

```
analyticView.xsodata/analyticView?$select=AMOUNT_SOLD,FAMILY_NAME&$filter=SALE_PRICE%20eq%20323.7&$format=json
```

but I am getting this error:

```
"Operator 'eq' incompatible with operand types 'Edm.Decimal' and 'Edm.Double'."
```

Could you please check what's the problem and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try adding an `M` to the end of the number you are filtering on.

```
$filter=SALE_PRICE%20eq%20323.7M
```

See [here](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview#AbstractTypeSystem) for more information